# Using spaces between specifiers

Tags: java

I've recently started learning JAVA. I am currently working on a few daily exercises, related to stdout and formatting.

Exercise:

> Each line of output must have 2 columns
>   1st column: string left justified to 15 characters
>   2nd column: integer expressed in three digits

I finally figured out a way and came up with:

```
System.out.format("%-15s %03d %n",s1 , x );
```

But when I ran the program there was an error.

Later when I removed the spaces between specifiers i.e.

```
System.out.format("%-15s%03d%n",s1 , x );
```

The code seemed to work.

Just wanted to know what difference does it make when space is not added.

Comment: Both lines compile but they provide different outputs.

Comment: What was the error for the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The added space(s) within the format string would be literal whitespaces. This means that you will get your 15 spaces from the beginning of the supplied string **plus** one whitespace which therefore makes a total spacing of 16. The same applies to the numerical value added to the output. The space after **%03d** would add an additional whitespace after the numerical value. Knowing this you can apply it to an example:

```
String s1 = "My Name";
int x = 61;
System.out.format("%-15s %03d %n", s1, x ); // Spaces in format.
System.out.format("%-15s%03d%n", s1, x );   // No Spaces in format.
```

The output will be:

```
My Name         061 
My Name        061
```

Whereas:

```
My Name         061 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|      16      ||4 |

My Name        061
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|     15      ||3|
```

This format (either way) **will not** generate an error. What will generate and error is if any one or both of the supplied variables to the **format()** method are of the wrong Data Type. Is the variable **s1** declared as a String and is the variable **x** declared as an decimal integer (**int**)? If not then you can end up with a **IllegalFormatConversionException**. [See Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for proper Converter Tags to use with the **format()** method.